# Justify a eigenstate of the hamiltionian

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, physics

I would just like so clarification is if possible in the words "Justify" in the question I have shown below:

[image: ammonia_diagram]

So when they say justify I assume they mean show?, so my answers is no, the reason being is a follows:

Justification 
$$\hat{H}\bar{x}=\lambda\bar{x}\:[1]$$

Given $\bar{x}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

substituting this in to RHS of equation [2]

I get the following
$$\begin{pmatrix}\epsilon _0&-\Delta \\ -\Delta &\epsilon _0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\epsilon _0\\ -\Delta \end{pmatrix}$$

So as the RHS of my equation [2] should be equal to my left of [2] which is not and I cannot factor anything from this equation as both are independent constants >0 it is shown that $|a\rangle$ is not an eigenstate.

Is this the type of justification they are requiring? I know you can you the determinant a calculate the eigenvalue and then the calculate the eigenstate that was but it seems a bit long winded.

Comment: Yes, justify means show/proof but since this is a problem in physics, the justification can be physical arguments instead of pure mathematical deductions. You justification is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the mathematical calculation, you can also offer a physical justification. Since it would not cost any energy to get from $|a>$ to $|b>$, it would be expected that the eigenstates are a linear combination of the two. If the Hamiltonian matrix is diagonal, your given states are eigenvectors. Since you have non-diagonal terms, those can be associated with a transition between the states. The two different eigenvalues, $\epsilon_0-\Delta$ and $\epsilon_0+\Delta$, correspond to eigenvectors $|a>+|b>$, and $|a>-|b>$.